# Samba Security - Set permissions for anyone write on share (root and others)

Tags: linux, permissions, samba

I have a server with Samba4. I need to configure the permissions for anybody can write on the share, but at the moment only the root users in the clients can write. How can i fix this?

My smb.conf

```
[global]
server string = SiteSintram
netbios name = SiteSintram
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
log file =  /var/log/samba/samba.log
map to guest = Bad user
guest account = nobody

[export]
comment = SETOP
path = /var/www/html/export
read only = no
public = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777

[export_b]
path = /smb/teste2
comment = teste
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
force user = root
force group = root
create mask = 0755
directory mask = 0755
```

Tanks a lot.

Edit 1:

The mask of folder on server is 777. When i mount this share on client, he assume the 755 mask. With this, users, except root, cant write on folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution .

The error occurs because the mount process is wrong . Just set the uid in the mount command. Like:

mount -t smbfs //ip/folder_a /mnt/foider_b -o uid=1005